# Scheduling a interactive session to start at bootup to access python script having dynamic web server

Tags: python, web-server

I remote onto a PI and run a Python script using simpleHTTPServer which continues to run as long as the PI is active. The command I run is:

sudo Python3.7 /home/pi/myscript.py 80

In conjunction with that, to setup its configuration from another device I use URL 'http://:80'  to update the configuration.

If instead I place the following line in the system level CRONTAB, all I get in the browser when accessing PI address in a browser is a folder listing.

How do I accomplish this in CRONTAB?

Thanks,
flowersj
Thanks, Rich

@reboot sudo Python3.7 /home/pi/myscript.py 80

Comment: *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*

Answer (score 2):

A code of thoughts:

- Python 3.7 is actually python3.7 (lowercase) or even python3 that may be the issue
- You may need to give a delay for the O/S to fully start
- Root may not have access to all the files depending on there location - cron jobs have very limited path settings.

I would try:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myscript.py 80
```

Sudo should not be needed if permissions are set correctly on objects.

Depending on whose crontab you edit the task can run as root automatically (`sudo crontab -e`) or as the logged in user (I assume pi but any user that is not root) (`crontab -e`)

Answer (score 0):

I mistyped, I did use 'python3.7' but later changed it to 'python3'
Used 'sudo crontab -e'
As to 'sudo'  I am using someone else's code so don't know about excessive permissions.

Got it to work this morning.  Had to add a 'cd'.

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the answer. Can you please elaborate a bit? Where do you have to add `cd`?

Comment: I'm presuming you are flowersrj as you have the same IP.  If you lost your login credentials, see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*.

Comment: Added a 'cd' as in change directory as a line before the call